# In determinate progress bar stopping in between the progress in windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i found a peculiar behavior of the progress bar , the progress bar animation stops in between the progress.

Details:-

1)  i have kept the progress bar  inside a stack panel named loading

2) i am using performance progress bar which a part of feb release

3) Just after  my service call is made, i am enabling the stack panel (which contains        progress bar)

4)After i get the data from the service call, i am disabling the stackpanel(which contains        progress bar)

But the problem is the progress bar is getting stuck in between the progress .

The same problem is present even if i use a normal progress bar also .

Am i doing anything wrong , can you correct me .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: <StackPanel Name="Loading" Margin="12,361,12,319" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text = "Downloading Data ..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" Name="txtblkDownloadingData"></TextBlock>
           
            <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Background="Red" IsIndeterminate="True"/>

        </StackPanel>

Answer (score 0):

I use to use coding4fun [progressOverlay control](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ProgressOverlay&referringTitle=Documentation) for such scenarios. Is easier and fits (I guess) with your requirements.

Check the link above, you'll find a sample on how it works and let us know if you have any problems.

regards,